# Silverlight Row Error

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I am usinq Ms Sql Server - Ado Net Entity Model and DomainService Class for connet to database from Silverlight.
I have A datagrid on my page 
if there is alot of row in my query my datagrid dont show anything.What can I do ? forexample i have  37.000 records on my query do i have to use MySql

Answer (score 0):

You need to limit your number of records in the grid, not switch databases.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd695920.aspx#id0420139

[DomainDataSource DataPager with silverlight 3 DataGrid & .Net RIA Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143155/domaindatasource-datapager-with-silverlight-3-datagrid-net-ria-services)